# Changing raster angle, raster width and build orientation in Ultimaker Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I want to try out different combinations of

- raster angle,
- raster width and
- build orientation

in Ultimaker Cura.

I don't see any settings where I could change these. I am using Cura 2.3

Any suggestions how I could change that?

Answer (score 4):

First: Update Ultimaker Cura. The latest is currently 3.5.1.

You can specify the angles and widths with the settings Infill Line Directions and Infill Line Width.

If you want them differently for different objects on the build plate you can specify those settings in the per-object settings menu on the left.